# Como acceder a una clase desde otra clase con Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

Estoy tratando de separar el codigo del display `i2c` en otro archivo ya que son muchas lineas en el `main.cpp`

Estoy utilizando `PlatformIO`, la clase esta dentro de una carpeta que cree llamada `Class`

Este es mi main

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "Class/Display.h"

Display lcd;
void setup() {
    lcd.bienvenida();
}

void loop() {
  // 
}
```

Y este es mi clase Display

```
#ifndef Display_h
#define Display_h


#include <Arduino.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

class Display;
class Display {

    private:
        LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd = LiquidCrystal_I2C(0x27,16,2);
    public:
        Display();
        void bienvenida();
};

Display::Display() {
    lcd.init();  
    lcd.backlight();
};

void Display::bienvenida() {
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(4,0);
    lcd.print("HOLA");
    lcd.setCursor(3,1);
    lcd.print("MUNDO");
};
#endif
```

Pero no funciona, si pongo todo el codigo de la clase en el main, entonces si funciona bien pero desde la clase no.

Se muy poco de c++ y estoy empezando a ver Arduino

Alguna solucion?

Comment: Prueba reemplazar `#include "Class/Display.h"` por `#include <Class/Display.h>`. Te puede servir leer [esta respuesta](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/17933/including-class-with-h-and-cpp-files).Saludos!

Comment: No funciona de niguna de las 2 formas

Comment: Qué error encuentras?

Comment: Falta información aquí: ¿ Que error te estás encontrando ? ¿ Donde están situados tus archivos (en que directorios) ?

Comment: Es que no hay error, el codigo compila y todo pero no muestra nada en el display, tengo el main.cpp en la raiz  y luego cree una carpeta llamada "Class" deonde guarde las clases

Comment: ¿Cómo estás compilando el código?

Comment: Como ocmpilo el codigo? Como se compila con PlatformIO, presionando un boton, el error pasa solo tratando de utilizar esta libreria en otra clase ya que tengo otra clase para controlar unos motores paso a paso y funciona bien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucione el problema con el codigo, cree un puntero al del tipo de la clase y luego en el setup instancie la clase. Creo que esas serian las palabras tecnicas

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Class/Display.h>

Display * lcd;
void setup() {
    lcd = new Display();
    lcd->bienvenida();
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```

Fuente: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/23168/library-liquidcrystal-i2c-dont-work-in-other-class-composition